# I have a function returning a vector of strings. It takes two strings and is to return the strings in one that are missing in the other

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector<string> missingWords(string s, string t) {
    //new array to hold s and t
    vector<string> arr;
    arr.push_back(s);
    arr.push_back(t);
    //loop through vector
    for(auto i=0; i <= arr.size(); i++)
        //erase t
        arr.erase(remove(arr.begin(), arr.end(), t), arr.end());
    return arr;
}
```

This function just deletes `t`, but I want to delete `t` completely so that if there are strings in `t` that are in `s` the strings in `s` will also be deleted.

Comment: *this function just deletes t but I want to delete t completely so that if there are strings in t that are in s the strings in s will also be deleted* What?  Can you give some sample input and output so we can better follow along with what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: A string doesn't contain strings; it normally contains characters. Do you mean you want the characters in one that are not present in the other? Or do you want to parse each string into sub-strings (e.g., words) then generate a list of the sub-strings in one that aren't present in the other?

Comment: for example is s is I love Houston and Texas and T is I texas. I would like to completely delete t from the array to print love Houston

Comment: I am not trying to do it by character. I want to do it by string in the array

Comment: @KwakuDabanka `for(auto i=0; i <= arr.size(); i++)` -- Using `<=` in a loop is almost always wrong.  In this case, you access an out-of-bounds entry.

Comment: C++ strings and vectors have no concept of English words.  As far as the compiler is concerned `s` and `t` are nothing more than ordered collections of characters.  If you want to treat them as a collection of words, you will have to write the necessary code to take a sentence such as "I love Houston and Texas" and break it into separate words yourself.

Comment: s and t are input strings i pushed into a vector. I would like for my vector to output the array with all the strings except for those in t. so if t has elements in s those strings/elements are also deleted

Comment: @KwakuDabanka *This function just deletes t, but I want to delete t completely so that if there are strings in t that are in s the strings in s will also be deleted.* -- Right, and doing such requires much more sophistication than your attempt.  That's the point that others are trying to make -- you can't merely take your code and give it a tweak here or there.

Comment: Given your title, this can be done by breaking up the sentence into individual words, storing those words in a container.  Then use `std::set_difference` on the two containers of words to get the words that are in one but not the other.  There is no need to `erase()` or delete words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the name `missingWords`, I'm going to guess that you want to take each input string, and tokenize it into words. Then you want to create an output that contains all the words present in one that aren't present in the other.

If that's correct, we might consider something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> missingWords(std::string const &a, std::string const &b)
{
    std::istringstream parse_a(a);
    std::vector<std::string> words_a(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(parse_a), {});

    std::istringstream parse_b(b);
    std::vector<std::string> words_b(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(parse_b), {});

    std::sort(words_a.begin(), words_a.end());
    std::sort(words_b.begin(), words_b.end());

    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::set_difference(words_a.begin(), words_a.end(), 
                        words_b.begin(), words_b.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

So, we start by breaking each string up into words. Then we sort the words in each vector. Then we find the difference between the two.

Note that as it stands right now, if one string contains two copies of a word, and the other contains only one copy of that word, this will show that word in the list of differences.

One easy way to eliminate that would be to use an `std::set` instead of an `std::vector` (and this lets us eliminate the sort as well):

```
std::vector<std::string> missingWords(std::string const &a, std::string const &b)
{
    std::istringstream parse_a(a);
    std::set<std::string> words_a(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(parse_a), {});

    std::istringstream parse_b(b);
    std::set<std::string> words_b(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(parse_b), {});

    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::set_difference(words_a.begin(), words_a.end(), 
                        words_b.begin(), words_b.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(ret));
    return ret;
}
```